# Open Windows application using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per requirement we need to open desktop application using javascript/jquery.

Please help me out to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this: [how to start up a desktop application in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265717/how-to-start-up-a-desktop-application-in-client-side)

It's not reaaly possible. You must either:

- Use ActiveX
- Install a browser plugin
- Find another solution to your problem

Comment: the funny thing about silly requirements is that it's often the users or the management who makes them :/

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig that makes sense, if they knew anything about these technologies they would never think of doing this :) (To be fair, some great ideas can also come to life from such naive/silly requirements that we, IT guys, may dismiss too quickly)

Answer (score 0):

If you could execute a file from client code you'll be facing an important security issue.

Imagine accessing a webpage that could, through javascript, start/stop windows services and launch common applications.

I think you can use Windows Scripting Host to launch some command line actions, however it will probably only work on IE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx