# How to launch a specific desktop application from browser

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm creating a C# ASP.NET website and from it I would like to launch the TeamViewer desktop application.

I've read around that there are security implications for this and that browsers may not allow this to prevent websites from taking control of computers (correct me if I'm wrong), however, if I log in to [TeamViewer's Management Console](https://login.teamviewer.com/), and try to connect to one of my registered devices, the website will try to launch TeamViewer, as seen below:

**1.**

[image: Connecting to computer]

**2.**

[image: Asking permission to launch app]

I'm not looking to launch any features of TeamViewer, only to launch the application and that's it. Is this possible using either C# or JavaScript? I would like this to work cross-platform and cross-browser as well.

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265717/how-to-start-up-a-desktop-application-in-client-side) I've came across.

Comment: Look at the URL in the window you pasted. If you made a link to that URL (assuming you had teamviewer installed) it should do exactly what you see there. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @dman2306 You're correct, simply navigating to `teamviewer8://' will prompt to open up the application. However, if TeamViewer is already opened and is running background, it will not pop up. But I'm sure there's nothing I can do to fix that.