# how to open the document in editable format in microsoft business account using php?

Tags: php, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I open the document (.docx) in editable format ? When I upload the doc file it will successfully viewed in drive of microsoft business account?

```
$uri ='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/roshan.docx:/content';
$headers = array( 'Content-Type: application/text', "Cache-Control: no- cache", "Pragma: no-cache", "Authorization: bearer ".$pppp ); 
$output = "";
$pointer = fopen($filpath, 'r+');
$stat = fstat($pointer);
$pointersize = $stat['size'];
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $pointer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, (int) $pointersize);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$output = json_decode($output, true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? The document can be edited either locally in Word or any other online service like O365 or Drive.

Comment: i want to open the word doc into drive of  word online..

Comment: $filepath = 'C:/abc.docx';

Comment: You might wanna look into relevant [API Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_put_content).

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has a free Extension, [Office Editing for Docs, Sheets, and Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj).

This extension allows you to open MS .docx files within Drive and edit them without needing to convert them first.

If you want to use Graph API and programmatically open from a web app, you can take a look at this thread which covers how to do this. [How to programmatically open a file located in OneDrive using desktop Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284652/how-to-programmatically-open-a-file-located-in-onedrive-using-desktop-word)