# JS, How can we open the desktop app from browser, like Zoom or Webex does

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

We all use Zoom or Webex to attend the meetings, then there is a popup that allows you to open the desktop app or you can continue on the web app. I want to implement a similar kind of user experience in my web application. But unable to understand how did they(zoom and Webex) did it.

I am not looking for a foolproof solution I just need to know the best approach to achieve it.

**Update:**

I am not doing it exactly like Zoom or Webex does. I have a button in my application so I am doing it onClick event.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265717/how-to-start-up-a-desktop-application-in-client-side)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to start up a desktop application in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265717/how-to-start-up-a-desktop-application-in-client-side)

Comment: I got the answer on the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser where they say about custom protocol like iTunes with "itms://" links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you must register a protocol on your OS (ie. you can use `protocol` lib to register a specific one in an Electron app), this would allow your app to be called with simple URIs like `myappprotocol://myappaction?myappparams`

Answer (score -1):

They make you install a client, that has caused many controversies since this is a gate for eventual security breaches

https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/zoom-zero-day-4-million-webcams-maybe-an-rce-just-get-them-to-visit-your-website-ac75c83f4ef5