# How to launch an app automatically from a link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have developed a Google Chrome App that in order for it to work, a Windows application should be running also.

I want to achieve something what Zoom does, for example, here https://zoom.us/test.

when one clicks on `Enter` button, if the application is not installed, installer is downloaded and after click on the exe, the application is run.

If the Zoom meeting application is already installed, browser just shows this confirmation message and after accept it, the application is opened.

[image: example]

How can this be done using JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: DId you check the accepted answer on this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63337125/5478462

Comment: Hello, I have read it and implemented, however, I did not find information about the way I can detect if an application is not installed and if it is not, the installer should be downloaded. For example, if I call customurl:// in the browser using JavaScript, and if the application is installed, it is run, however, if the application is not installed, and that URL is called in Chrome, the Google search page appears with the result of customurl://. Do you know how to do it?